# Is there a way to use a Python executable with a database without installing a database on the target PC?

Tags: python, mysql

I'm working on a huge Python project in which I'm storing my data in a (local) MySQL database. If I want to execute my project as a .exe, is it possible to use this .exe on another PC without the hassle of installing a new local MySQL-Server on this PC?

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to SO. If you want to embed a database in your executable, you should use an embeddable database such as sqlite : https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/sqlite3.html

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!